# create UUID that won't collide with other systems

Tags: python, uuid

I am using the Python standard [`uuid`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) library.  If my application eventually scales out to multiple servers, what should I be doing to ensure that the UUIDs don't collide, since the different systems will be using different machine ids?  Which of the UUID generators should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`uuid1()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1) should be sufficient for your needs, since it takes the host ID into account.

In [section 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.2.2) of RFC 4122, this is the key bit:

> - Set the node field to the 48-bit IEEE address in the same order of significance as the address.

The node field is the last 6 bytes of the UUID and will reflect one of the MAC addresses of the host in question.

Comment: wouldn't each computer running this application have a different host id?  therefor increasing the chances of collision?

Comment: Why would having different host IDs *increase* the chances of collision...?  Surely each host having its own node field (if correctly filled-in) would prevent it?